# Hide and show widgets in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new for dart.

I have a class for items contains an integer for id and a bool for visibility.

```
class Item{
  item(this.name,  this.isVisible);
  final int id;
  bool isVisible;

}
```

And there's another function returns widgets

```
Widget _buildwithItem(Item item){
  return Visibility(
    visible: item.isVisible,
    child:Text(item.id.toString())
  );

}
```

Now I need to create many items as an array

```
List<Item> items = <Item>[];
List<Widget> widgets = <Widget>[];
createItems();
items.foreach((element)widgets.add(_buildwithItem(element)));
```

Now I put these Widgets inside a column and add a button ,
click this button will search an id in items that

```
item.id = id
```

When item found, I'll set

```
item.isVisible = !item.isVisible;
```

I want to hide/show the widget for this item as the same time, how to do this?

I had tried to set key for each Visibility but the visible value is final so I can't edit it directly.

I had tried to move build fonction inside class Item but still not working.

Comment: Could you please show your build method ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a whole new instance of Item and then then replace the previous instance of I obviously don't know what you code looks like but you probably want to do something like this.

```
setState((){
items[itemFound] = Item(items[itemFound].id, !items[itemsFound].isVisible)
)};
```